# Induced structure of topological group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology

If we consider a closed Jordan curve $\mathcal{C}$, I know that it's homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. Now I take an homeomorphism $\phi:S^1\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and this homeomorphism induces a structure (If my attempt is correct! xD) of topological gorup on $\mathcal{C}$.

In fact we can define an operation $\star_{\phi}$ on $\mathcal{C}$ as follows 
$$p\star_{\phi}q:=\phi(\phi^{-1}(p) \cdot \phi^{-1}(q)), \: \forall p,q\in \mathcal{C}$$

where $\cdot$ is the canonical moltiplication of complex numbers. Now, it's clear that the operation $\star_{\phi}$ depends from the choice of $\phi$. A more explicit description of these operations can be given if we have more information about the group $\mathcal{Hom}(S^1,S^1)$ of the homeomorphisms from $S^1$ in $S^1$.

Any reference is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: More information about $\mathcal{Hom}(S^1,S^1)$ :)

Comment: What does Hom mean here? From what you've written I can't tell whether you want topological group homomorphisms (then it's just $\mathbb{Z}$; this is standard) or homeomorphisms.

Comment: With $\mathcal{Hom}(S^1,S^1)$ I denote the group of homeomorphisms from $S^1$ in $S^1$.